# devexpress xtraReporting displaying wrong data compared to what SqlServer says it should?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

I currently am trying to generate a report from a stored procedure with a start time, an end time and a customer ID. In the reports code behind I have:

```
Imports DXProjectTimer.dsReportingTableAdapters

Public Class rptCompDetail
    Protected Sub demanded() Handles Me.DataSourceDemanded
        Dim spcomptime As dsReporting.tsp_Get_Report_ProjectsByCustDataTable = New dsReporting.tsp_Get_Report_ProjectsByCustDataTable
        Dim pid As System.Nullable(Of Integer)
        Tsp_Get_Report_ProjectsByCustTableAdapter1.Fill(spcomptime, Parameters.Item("CompanyID").Value, pid, Parameters.Item("StartTime").Value, Parameters.Item("EndTime").Value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and in the page with the Report viewer i have:

```
Protected Sub createReport(startDate As DateTime, endDate As DateTime)
    Dim report As New rptCompDetail()

    report.CompanyID.Value = Session("CompanyID")
    report.StartTime.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)
    report.EndTime.Value = DateTime.Now

    ReportViewer1.Report = report
End Sub
```

(ive substituted the use of the functions parameters for direct datetime calls for debugging for now)

now when i open the site, the chart displays nothing! but if I open the SqlServer Profiler, i can see the Query

```
exec dbo.tsp_Get_Report_ProjectsByCust @intCompanyID=7,@intCustomerID=NULL,@dteStart='2013-12-10 10:44:08.413',@dteEnd='2014-02-10 10:44:08.413'
```

is ran properly, and when i run that myself in SqlServer i get 2 rows with the correct 2 columns and the correct data inside. the chart DOES show one of the values if i change the StartTime to `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-99)`, but the value it uses is less than half of the true value and the second row is not displayed. This is a very frustrating problem and i cannot begin to imagine what is causing it, can somebody please point out what it is im doing wrong.

(FYI the function is called like this:)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        SetDefaults()
        AddTimeOptions()
    End If
    createReport(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), DateTime.Now)
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably time portion of datetime (it's the usual suspect)

Comment: @MitchWheat what do you mean? When i run the command picked up by the SqlServer profiler the SQL parameters do have the correct dates and the query returns the correct data.